# Как добавить условие не применять скидку к определенным товарам

Tags: битрикс

На сайте установленна система скидок (Применять скидку 5% на любой товар ,  если в корзине больше 1 товара) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как не применять скидку на определнные разделы товаров ?

Comment: какая у вас версия bitrix ?

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий 18.0.2

Comment: тогда вам нужно использовать предустановленный список маркетинговых акций https://yadi.sk/i/efcZOwpY1degug там вы на раздел сможете задать скидки какие нужно

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий спасибо!